# Compare two dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to compare two different data frames of pandas. Both the data set are identical but the data frame equal gives false. (df3 == df4) . Why df2 == df3 gives false for each row ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) method

```
df3.equals(df4)
```

You can also compare two `df` with [compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html)

---

Here is an issue talking about [None is not equal to None](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20442)